# What is __NSCFArray in AFNetworking 2.0 response?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, afnetworking

What is `__NSCFArray` in this AFNetworking 2.0 response:

```
- (void)loadData:(NSMutableArray *) resDic
{
    ... 
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {            
        NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject class]);  //__NSCFArray   
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

How can I convert it to NSArray?

Comment: It already is an NSArray.  Difficult to determine if it's a mutable one, though.

Comment: @HotLicks Wouldn't `[responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]` do the trick for that?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - Nope.  That does not work reliably.  In fact there does not appear to be a reliable way to determine if an NSArray is mutable (other than to try mutating it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSArray` is a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).  This basically means that `NSArray` objects could be made up of one of several different actual implementations and `__NSCFArray` is one of the classes (probably the most common) that `NSArray` can use to implement an array.

Just use the `__NSCFArray` as you would any other `NSArray` and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is already an `NSArray`, something you can verify by calling:

```
BOOL isKindOfArray = [responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]];
```

NSArray is implemented as a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) and one of the private subclasses that it might return is `__NSCFArray`.

The point of a class cluster is that the framework can provide different implementations under the hood that you don't really have to care about. As far as you should be concerned, it's an NSArray.